# Flask static image url won't generate

Tags: python, flask

I'm having some trouble with getting Flask to serve images I downloaded.

Python:

```
r = requests.get(image_url)
    with open(f"static/image{i}.jpg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)

    # Add the image to the list of images
    images.append(f"image{i}.jpg")

return render_template('story.html', paragraphs=paragraphs, images=images)
```

Html:

```
  <body>
<h1>Story</h1>
{% for paragraph in paragraphs %}
  <p>{{ paragraph }}</p>
  <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=images[i] }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Resulting page source code:

```
<h1>Story</h1>

  <p>Once upon a time there was a young girl named Maria who was in a long distance relationship with her boyfriend, John. John lived in a different city and they could only see each other once every few months.</p>
  <img src="/static/">

  <p></p>
  <img src="/static/">

  <p>Whenever they met, they would talk and laugh and enjoy each other&#39;s company, but Maria couldn&#39;t help but feel like something was missing. She was feeling lonely and unsure about the future of their relationship.</p>
  <img src="/static/">

  <p></p>
  <img src="/static/">
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
The images array isn't empty, it prints all the image filenames. Also a bit weird that under each paragraph there are two images.

Comment: you are missing a closing parenthesis in your `url_for` function. and `[i]` is not known to your jinja template - at least you dont show it in the snippet you shared

Answer (score 0):

```
 {% for paragraph in paragraphs %}
  <p>{{ paragraph }}</p>
  <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=images[loop.index]) }}">
{% endfor %}
```

This was the solution.